# jmockit and static initialization

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmockit

We are using Jmockit for unit test and we have questions about mocking of the static initialization of a class. When we mock a class by declaring it as (@Mocked final) in the function parameter, we expect the static initialization of this class is mocked as well, but it is not. Here is a sample showing the problem.

```
class TmpClass {

    static public int method1(){
        System.out.println("AClass method1 is called");
        return 10;
    }

    static public int method2(){
        System.out.println("AClass method2 is called");
        return 20;
    }


}

class Utils {
    static public int sInt = TmpClass.method1();
    public int pInt = TmpClass.method2();

    static public int method(){
        System.out.println("Should NOT be called when Utils is mocked.");
        return 1000;
    }

}

class ClassToTest {

    public int foo(){
        return Utils.method();
    }

    public int goo(){
        return Utils.sInt;
    }

}

public class TestPost {

    @Test
    public void test(@Mocked final Utils mocked) {
        System.out.println("This should show 0 as expected since Utils is mocked: " + new ClassToTest().foo());
        System.out.println("This should show 0 as expected since Utils is mocked: " + mocked.pInt);

        System.out.println("This should be 0 but it is not: " + new ClassToTest().goo());
        System.out.println("This should be 0 but it is not: " + mocked.sInt);
    }

}
```

Here we have a ClassToTest that we want to test. It depends on a class called Utils. So we mocked Utils by declaring (@Mocked fine Utils mocked) in the function parameter. After this, 
1. The static method Utils.method is mocked as expected. So ClassToTest.foo returns 0 as expected. 
2. But static variable Utils.sInt is not mocked. TmpClass.method1 is actually called, and Utils.sInt is assigned 10. 
3. The member variable Utils.pInt is mocked. mocked.pInt shows as 0 as expected.

Because of 2 above, TmpClass.method1 is called. Since we don't want to execute TmpClass in our test env, the next thing we try is to put the following into TestPost.

```
@BeforeClass
static public void init(){
    new MockUp<Utils>(){
        @Mock
        public void $clinit(){

        }
    };
}
```

But this does NOT work. TemClass.method1 is still called! We have to mocked TmpClass directly in order to stop it from being executed.

So our questions:

1. Is it the expected behavior that static initialization code is still executed even if a class is declared as @Mocked in the parameter?
2. Why does the BeforeClass code above fail to mock up the static initialization code of Utils?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: This whole question boils down to not making good use of the Java IDE one is using. If the developer simply looked at the API documentation for `@Mocked` (which any IDE provides easy access to), he would see a paragraph saying: "Static class initializers (including assignments to static fields) of a mocked class are not affected, unless specified otherwise."

Comment: I see. Then how about question 2? If we want to specifically mock the static initialization of the mocked class, it doesn't work as shown by the sample code. The problem we have right now is that the dependecy just keeps on growing, and eventually some third party class code is executed in the test evn, which we don't want. If we can not mock the initialization code of the mocked class, then we have to mock the classes that the mocked class depends on. Theoretically the number could be big.

Comment: It does work. If you add a `System.out.println(Utils.sInt);` line at the end of the `@BeforeClas` method, it will print "0" as desired. The reason it appears to not work in the `test(@Mocked final Utils mocked)` method is simply that the `@Mocked` parameter cancelled the effects of the mock-up that was previously applied. Tests are not supposed to apply `MockUp` and `@Mocked` to the same class in a way that one overlaps the other.